# Programatically delete several attributes in _product_attributes in post meta

Tags: post-meta

First i tried this one

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'hooker');
function hooker(){

    delete_post_meta( 1054, 'Душ, шт.');
    delete_post_meta( 1054, 'Ванная, шт.');
    delete_post_meta( 1054, 'Кол-во пользователей');
}
```

It doesn't work, i understood they are in array and i need something like this:

```
$attributes = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes' );
```

Than find ones i need and do

```
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
```

Is it a proper way to do this? How can I delete that attributes in array?

Comment: `delete_post_meta` needs 3 arguments : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta

Comment: @mmm thanx, but the problem is that _product_attributes is an array itself, i cannt delete it all